# Flutter: show rewardedAd when it is loaded

Tags: flutter, admob, flutter-dependencies, google-mobile-ads

To show the ad I do this:

```
await adState.showRewardedAd();
await adState.rewardedAd!.show(onUserEarnedReward: (RewardedAd ad, RewardItem reward) {
// reward
});
```

and:

```
Future createRewardedAd([bool showVideo = false]) async {
    await RewardedAd.load(
      adUnitId: rewardeUnitAdId,
      request: request,
      rewardedAdLoadCallback: RewardedAdLoadCallback(
        onAdLoaded: (RewardedAd ad) async {
          adState.rewardedAd = ad;
          _numRewardedLoadAttempts = 0;
          if (showVideo) {
            showRewardedAd();
          }
        },
        onAdFailedToLoad: (LoadAdError error) async {
          adState.rewardedAd = null;
          _numRewardedLoadAttempts += 1;
          if (_numRewardedLoadAttempts <= maxFailedLoadAttempts) {
            await createRewardedAd();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> showRewardedAd() async {
    if (adState.rewardedAd == null) {
      return await createRewardedAd(true);
    }

    adState.rewardedAd!.fullScreenContentCallback =
        await FullScreenContentCallback(
      onAdShowedFullScreenContent: (RewardedAd ad) => {},
      onAdDismissedFullScreenContent: (RewardedAd ad) async {
        ad.dispose();
        await createRewardedAd();
      },
      onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent: (RewardedAd ad, AdError error) async {
        ad.dispose();
        await createRewardedAd();
      },
    );
  }
```

So every time we close the rewardAd we create/load it again to have it prepared for next time. Until here everything is fine.

---

The problem comes when we click to show it again too fast.
When we do:

```
if (adState.rewardedAd == null) {
      return await createRewardedAd(true);
    }
```

I'm forcing it to be loaded and I wait for `await RewardedAd.load()` BUT despite I wait for that, the `onAdLoaded` event takes some time and the async function doesn't know it's not ready yet.

So, when I do `await adState.rewardedAd!` it can be null.

How could I make this more secure? Google's documentation is not covering this